# Deserialize a List<T> json.net in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I am a new user of Json.NET. I have created a type: `Person` that has different attributes: firstName, lastName, age, etc.

I have a Json string but I can't manage to deserialize it and get all the "Person" in a stored list.

Here is my piece of code I am running:

```
List <Person> persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(strPersons);`
```

strPersons is my json string. It is like that:

```
string strPersons = @"{
    'Columns':['FirstName','LastName','Hobbies','Age','Country','Address','Phone','Gender'],
    'Rows':[ 
       ['X', 'Y', 'Cuisine', '35', 'France', 'unknown', 'unknown', 'male'],      
       ['W', 'Z', 'Danser', '43', 'France', 'unknown', 'unknown', 'male'],
        ...]
```

My error when compiling is:

> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type System.Collections.Generic.List1[Info3JsonConvertor.Person]' because the type requires a JSON array

Can someone explain me how can I deserialize my json string to get a list
Will I have the same problem if I serialize a `List<Person>` into json string?
I know those questions have already been answered but if someone can explain me with my example?

Comment: "My error when compiling" that doesn't sound like a compile-time error. Please provide a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem. But note that your `strPersons` only defines a single object, with fields of `Columns` and `Rows`. It's *not* an array...

Comment: You should add in the details of your `Person` object that you are trying to deserialize it into. Chances are the c# object doesn't match your json object in some way. In fact you are trying to deserialize it into a list but as the error says your json object isn't an array, it is two properties, row and column. What data do you expect to actually come out of this json into your list person?

Comment: Pro tip: Copy the Json string to your clipboard, then in Visual Studio, Edit menu, Paste Special and select `Paste JSON as Classes`. That will give you an object you can deserialise into.

Comment: @DavidG: That is an awesome pro tip. Will have to remember that one next time I need to make classes for some json (which in fact will be soon).

Comment: @Chris yeah, i understood, i was expecting to get a List<Person> I thought json.net read my rows as new person

Comment: @DavidG awesome protip ! Thanks for this advice. I will do it next time

Comment: @Chris Indeed, every time I work with JSON this saves me countless hours building boilerplate code. In fact I've spent the last week coding against a new API from a third party and have dozens of such classes created in this way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root element is an object not a list or array (`{....}`). Json arrays start with `[`

```
public class MyData
{
    public List<string> Columns { set; get; }
    public List<List<string>> Rows { set; get; }
}
```

---

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I must practise more to get it on my own next time

Answer (score 1):

The object that the deserializer recognizes from your JSON looks something like that:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<string> Columns { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see it's not List, but just Person

Comment: In fact I suspect that Rows is actually `List<Person>` based on the data in it and that the OP actually wants to just get `Rows` out as `List<Person>`.

Comment: If that's the case, than either there's need to add wrapper object, and than get just the rows or fix the JSON response to suit the expected data (if it's an option)

Comment: Yup. I mentioned it because if that is the case then it wouldn't take much change to your objet for it to be the wrapper object in question.

Comment: @FelixAv as mentionned, I want my Rows ( <=> List<Person>) to be deserialized in a List<Person>